# AttributeError: tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.layers.experimental' has no attribute 'SyncBatchNormalization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to run a tensorflow Object Detection API and i am stuck with the error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.layers.experimental' has no attribute 'SyncBatchNormalization'
```

How do i fix this?

My versions are:
keras-applications 1.0.8
keras-nightly 2.5.0.dev2021032900
keras-preprocessing 1.1.2
tensorflow 2.1.0

Comment: It would be helpful to share the code you're trying to run, otherwise we can't help

Answer (score 0):

Check the TensorFlow documentation correctly.[`tf.keras.layers.experimental.SyncBatchNormalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/SyncBatchNormalization) is available in the latest TF build i.e `v2.5.0`.

This layer is not included in TensorFlow 2.1.0. Update your TensorFlow package using

```
pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
```